# How to Store OAuth Credentials With Gnome Keyring

Tags: oauth, vala, gnome-keyring-daemon

I'm trying to build a simple Vala/Gtk Twitter app, and I've managed to send tweets; however, the user has to authenticate every time, which entails going to a URL, clicking to give my App permission to post, copying the PIN, and pasting said PIN into my App. For each tweet.

I'd like to store this authentication information in the GNOME Keyring; however, I barely know anything about OAuth and I know nothing about the Keyring.

How can I store OAuth data into the Gnome Keyring? I'll accept answers in any language, although bonus points will be awarded for Vala answers. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use *libsecret* library which communicates with "Secret Service" through Dbus protocol .

First you need to define a password schema , which will be used later for token store/extraction .

Vala example :

```
var example_schema = new Secret.Schema ("org.yor_schema.name",Secret,SchemaFlags.NONE,
    "number", Secret.SchemaAttributeType.INTEGER,
    "string", Secret.SchemaAttributeType.STRING);
```

Now you should store your token :

```
var attributes = new GLib.HashTable<string,string> ();
attributes["number"] = "18";
attributes["string"] = "Hello";

Secret.password_storev.begin(example_schema,attributes,Secret.COLLECTION_DFAULT,
    "Label","Token",null,(obj,async_res) => {
        bool res = Secret.password_store.end(async_res);
        /* Password has been stored - do something ... */
});
```

To extract stored token :

```
var attributes = new GLib.HashTable<string,string> ();
attributes["number"] = "18";
attributes["string"] = "Hello";

Secret.password_lookupv.begin(example_schema,attributes,null,(obj,async_res) => {
    String token = Secret.password_lookup.end(async_res);
});
```

The package name called `libsecret-1` .

To compile , add following flag to your makefile .

```
AM_VALAFLAGS = \
    --pkg=libsecret-1
```

Comment: Sorry, I've long since given up on this project (it was more of a learning exercise and the benefit/time rate isn't high enough to merit further investment). At a glance, it looks right, so I'll +1, but I can't justify the time to verify your solution.